# list of paren via regular expression?

Tags: .net, regex

I need to construct a regular expression that breaks apart a string like this
(1 2 3);(a b c);(4 5 6)

i.e. each thing in parenthesis is a blob (or a list to be pulled apart next)

Any thoughts?

Here's a link that I found on this.  I haven't been able to get this to work under .net so far.  If you can do a translation, that would be appreciated.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=574517

Comment: Just for the challenge, here is the regex expression: `(?<=(^|;)\()(?<list>[^();]+)(?=\)(;|$))`.  It defines the start of a list as the start of a string or a semicolon followed by an open paren and only considers each list to be ended if it encounters a close paren followed by a semicolon of the end of the string.  "list" is the named group containing (you guessed it) each list.

Comment: @Mark M: do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: If you only care about extracting data inside parentheses (and don't mind if the string contains other information), use this: `\((?<blob>.*?)\)`

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be achieved using [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string[] results = myString.Split("();".ToCharArray(), 
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// results[0] == "1 2 3"
// results[1] == "a b c"
// results[2] == "4 5 6"
```

Comment: +1 true... and if you'd like to walk through it with a state machine (ie. it might not be a flat list)

Comment: @sgtz - True (and a RegEx _is_ a state machine). My point is to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: yep.  That's kind of why I mentioned it.  Thanks for the Split suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment above:

Just for the challenge, here is the regex expression:

`(?<=(^|;)\()(?<list>[^();]+)(?=\)(;|$))`

It defines the start of a list as the start of a string or a semicolon followed by an open paren and only considers each list to be ended if it encounters a close paren followed by a semicolon of the end of the string. "list" is the named group containing (you guessed it) each list.

Comment: please add this add code.  This works fine.  Thanks.              var s = "(1,2);(3,4)";
            var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=(^|;)\()(?<list>[^();]+)(?=\)(;|$))");
            var o = regex.Matches(s);
            var l0 = o[0];
            var l1 = o[1];

Comment: this doesn't work for inner parenthesis.  Found a perl link for this.  So far, I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: What sort of inner parenthesis situations need to be handled?  Can you post some examples?

Comment: Examples of not only the input, but how you want the output for those cases too.